# finding number of competitors on an airport using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am reviewing a dataset on flights and airport details. The dataset contains the following columns with the data about airport and flight details.

| flight_date | op_career | tail_num | flight_num | origin | origin_airport_ID | dest_airport_ID | dest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/13/2019 | AA | N900EV | 3503 | SFO | 11308 | 10397 | LAX |
| 03/13/2019 | AA | N900EZ | 3502 | SFO | 11308 | 10397 | LAX |
| 03/13/2019 | AS | N686BR | 3397 | SFO | 11308 | 10397 | LAX |
| 03/13/2019 | YV | N932LR | 5804 | SFO | 11308 | 10397 | LAX |
| 03/14/2019 | DL | 255NV | 515 | SFO | 11308 | 10397 | LAX |

I want to find the number of competitors on each airport.I am working with dplyr and I want to create a summary file which shows the airport and the competitors on that airport.

| Airport | competitors |
| --- | --- |
| SFO | 4 |
| LAX | 4 |

I know you dont use count function in summary. I am just having trouble writing a function in summary file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(origin, dest) %>% 
  summarise(competitors = n_distinct(op_career), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = origin:dest, names_to = NULL,
    values_to = 'Airport') %>%
  select(Airport, competitors)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Airport competitors
  <chr>         <int>
1 SFO               4
2 LAX               4
```

Comment: If the input data has a line where origin and dest are swapped, and that should be counted the same, can modify `group_by` e.g. `df %>% 
  group_by(one = pmax(origin, dest), two = pmin(origin, dest)) %>% 
  summarise(n = n_distinct(op_career), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  pivot_longer(-n, values_to = 'Airport') %>% 
  select(Airport, n)` (Otherwise output will have dupes)